# Some ideas about numbers.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, real-numbers, transcendental-numbers

(Please all of you be patient and give me your feedbacks whether the following ideas false or true ,whether they are useful or useless, also tell me in your opinions how can I improve these ideas if they are good.)Consider the following set :

$\{0.1,0.01,0.001,...\}=\{10^{-n}:n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

then  $\lim_{n \to \infty} 10^{-n}=m $ (I consider m in the context of my ideas that it is the smallest positive real number)

Let

$M=\{...L_{-1}=-1-m$ ,L_{0}=-m (the largest negative number) , L_{1}=1-m=0.999999.... ,... }

={L_{r}=r-m : $r \in \mathbb{Z}$ }$ **(I know  0.999...=1 it has proof but it is still not convincing in my opinion)

Can I consider elements of set $M$ irrationals of type transcendental?

Following I want to show you this idea using m (the smallest positive real number from above):

Let $s=((90-m)degrees$

$\tan{(s)}=\frac{\sin {(s)}}{\cos{(s)}}=\frac{1-m}{m}=\frac{1}{m}-1$(very big number)   while  $\sec{(s)}=\frac{1}{\cos{(s)}}=\frac{1}{m}$ (also very big number)

so can I say  that  $\tan{(s)}$ < $\sec{(s)}$?

Comment: there is no smallest positive real number $\left(\dfrac\epsilon 2<\epsilon \text{ if } \epsilon>0\right)$

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty} 10^{-n} = 0$. There is no smallest positive real number.

Comment: By standard analysis, $\lim_{n \to \infty} 10^{-n} =0$ nothing more. There is no "smallest positive real" in standard analysis. But you might want to look up "hyperreal numbers".

Comment: @Deepak       If I want to read about these hyperreal numbers...what is the name of course I need to study it? and what are its prerequisites?

Comment: @Mahmoudalbahar That I'm not sure about, I am an amateur enthusiast who learned these things myself (autodidact). Not sure what level they're covered at (if at all non-standard analysis is taught, it should be at least a University course).

Comment: I was also going to suggest "hyperreal numbers."  You could read about them on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number)

Comment: Adding to @J.W.Tanner's suggestion, the book "Surreal Numbers" by Donald Knuth is very readable for someone without an extensive background. It will still require a careful reading and will only be grasped if you break out a pencil and follow along.

Comment: Hyperreal numbers are, by definition, *not* real numbers. You can study them in their own right but when you ask if these are transcendental the answer is *NO*.  Transcendental numbers are real numbers.  And your "smallest positive number" does not exist in real analysis. You say your proof that $0.9999.... = 1$ is not convincing but the fact that $\lim_{n\to \infty} 10^{-n} = 0$ *because* there is no lowest positive integer *is* the proof.  Is that not convincing?

Comment: If $m$ is the smallest positive number, then what is $\frac {m}{10}$?

Comment: @fleablood    the result of limit is the closest number   not exact value(this word showed my flaw it seems like 0 is the closest)....
your explanation is 100% correct  but my intention when I said it is not convincing because 0.9999... looks like it is smaller than one.
and I called m the smallest I mean by it number as 0.000....01 (has infinite zeros between the first zero and last one )
But I am very grateful for the support and guide from all of you who react and show me my mistakes.

Comment: @fleablood  for $\frac{m}{10}$ I forgot to think about it.

Comment: @fleablood   I felt them like they are transcendental   because they are similar a little bit.
but it turned out to be false ...I should learn more and I should be careful.

Comment: I think you are confusing the concept of $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n$ as somehow being an $a_k$ term where $k$ is really really high.  That is *not* what a limit is.  A limit is what the terms *APPROACH*, it is not actually any of the terms themselves and the limit need not have any characteristic of the terms.  The $10^{-n}$ themselves are really small and "get close to $0$" but every one of them is bigger then $0$ and none of them are the smallest $10^{-k}$  But $\lim 10^{-n}$ is not *any* of those terms.  And the limit doesn't *approach* $0$.  It ***IS*** $0$.  Exactly!....

Comment: ....  I know that $0.999999....$ *looks* smaller than $1$ and I can "forgive" that but concepts of "the smallest positive number" and $0.0000.....0001$ with an infinite number of $0$s before the $1$, should be immediately recognizable as nonsensical. Any positive number can be halved, and you can't have anything *after* an infinite number of $0$s because the infinite number of zeros can't ever end....  Now this may seem puzzling and contradictory as what *can* $0.9999...$ be if $1-0.9999....$ can't make any sense...but is does if $\lim 10^{-n}=0$.  Which is does.

Comment: @fleablood   I am grateful for your kindness of discussing my ideas , highlighting on what my mistakes are and clarifying the correct information .